# Why this function is not calling properly?

Tags: python, pandas, list, function

```
def func_list(l):
    t=list()
    z=list(l)
    for i in range(0,len(z)-1):

        if(z[i]==' '):continue
        a=z[i].split(':')
        if(a[0]==''): continue

        for j in range(i+1,len(z)-1):
            b=z[j].split(':')

            if(b[0]==' '): break
            if a[0]==b[0]:

                z[i]=z[i]+' '+b[1]
                z[j]=' '
            else:
                t.append(z[i])
                break

    return t
```

`df_head['Message']=df_head['Message'].apply(func_list)`

When calling this function I am getting this error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-d8f85a0144bf> in <module>
----> 1 df_head['Message']=df_head['Message'].apply(func_list)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-40-00055f2d4f69> in func_list(l)
     14             if a[0]==b[0]:
     15 
---> 16                 z[i]=z[i]+' '+b[1]
     17                 z[j]=' '
     18             else:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: df_head['Message']=df_head['Message'].apply(func_list)  is this how you call a function?

Comment: Seems to be an index error on your function. Knowing that the error is not originating when `z[i]` gets initiated, my best guess is that during ```b=z[j].split(':')```, the new list ```b``` is not populated as you originally thought (with two indexes).

Comment: if a[0]==b[0] if this will true then z[i]=z[i]+' '+b[1] b[1] does not give any value it will give error that b[1] list out of index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add check for length of b and then use b[1] for next processing e.g.

```
def func_list(l):
    t=list()
    z=list(l)
    for i in range(0,len(z)-1):

        if(z[i]==' '):continue
        a=z[i].split(':')
        if(a[0]==''): continue

        for j in range(i+1,len(z)-1):
            b=z[j].split(':')

            if(b[0]==' '): break
            if a[0]==b[0] and len(b)>1:

                z[i]=z[i]+' '+b[1]
                z[j]=' '
            else:
                t.append(z[i])
                break

    return t
```

Comment: Best guess to the error without knowing the data inside ```df_head['Message']```, good answer.

Comment: ['[',
 "'",
 'P',
 'r',
 'a',
 't',
 'h',
 'e',
 'e',
 'k',
 'P',
 'r',
 'a',
 't',
 'h',
 'e',
 'e',
 'j',
 'u',
 's',
 'j',
 'o',
 'i',
 'n',
 'e',
 't',
 'h',
 'i',
 'c',
 'h',
 'a',
 't',
 '.',
 "'",
 "'",
 'P',
 'r',
 'a',
 't',
 'h',
 'e',
 'e',
 'k',
 'H',
 'i',
 "'",
 "'",
 'P',
 'r',
 'a',
 'v',
 'e',
 'e',
 'n',
 'P',
 'r',
 'a',
 'v',
 'e',
 'e',
 'j',
 'u',
 's',
 'j',
 'o',
 'i',
 'n',
 'e',
 't',
 'h',
 'i',
 'c',
 'h',
 'a',
 't',
 '.',
 "'",
 "'",
 'P',
 'r',
 'a',
 'v',
 
 'n', I received this.